# How do I send data to destination view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a segue and I want to set a custom property of the destination view controller, ClueDetailViewController. I can't tell what's wrong with this code, but it crashes during runtime with the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa802f9cb20" (the destination view controller).

ClueDetailViewController.h (the destination):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ClueDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property NSString *testString;

@end
```

In TheHuntViewController.m (where the segue was triggered):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showClue"])
    {
        ClueDetailViewController *viewController = (ClueDetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

        viewController.testString = @"This is a test"; // causes runtime crash
    }
}
```

Please help! Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the full error message:

```
2015-03-09 12:29:32.636 InternetOfDrinks1[93005:14003302] -[UINavigationController setTestString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa802f9cb20
2015-03-09 12:29:32.638 InternetOfDrinks1[93005:14003302] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setTestString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa802f9cb20'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f8df35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104c26bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f9504d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104eed27c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104eece18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   InternetOfDrinks1                   0x000000010466d356 -[TheHuntTableViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 422
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001058cc71c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 151
    7   InternetOfDrinks1                   0x000000010466d17e -[TheHuntTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 142
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000105462393 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1293
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001054624d4 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010539d331 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010539d1ab _afterCACommitHandler + 516
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104ec2dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104ec2d20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104eb8b53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104eb8486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010855c9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010537a420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    18  InternetOfDrinks1                   0x000000010466e553 main + 115
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010751d145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Please can you post the full error message

Comment: How do you present ClueDetailViewController? Is it pushed to navigation stack (UINavigationViewController)?

Comment: @Greg I present it modally.

Comment: @Popeye I added the full error to the question.

Comment: @amacrobert from the error message you get UINavigationController as the destination view controller so you have to grab the top vc and you should be fine, please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you add it to UINavigationViewController stack, try this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showClue"])
    {
       UINavigationController *dest = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        ClueDetailViewController *viewController = (ClueDetailViewController *)dest.topViewController;

        viewController.testString = @"This is a test"; // causes runtime crash
    }
}
```

Comment: OK that was a waste. Was about to hit submit when your answer appeared saying near enough the same thing +1 from me.